# How to avoid subsection appearance in one place on latex?

Tags: latex

I am writing a document on latex(overleaf) with the following pattern.

```
**\Section{1}
\subsection{1.1}
\begin{fig}
\end{fig}
\section{2}
\subsection{2.1}
\begin{fig}
\end{fig}
\subsection{2.2}
\begin{fig}
\end{fig}
\section{3}
\subsection{3.1}
\begin{fig}
\end{fig}**
```

Instead of following this pattern, all sections and subsections are shown at the beginning of first page followed by all figures.

what can be the possible error?

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Answer (score -1):

Some times without text it was difficult to float the figures or tables. I have alternative solution.

Use this environment `figurehere` macro in preamble.

```
\newenvironment{figurehere}[1]
{\noindent\begin{minipage}{#1}\parindent\z@\def\@captype{figure}}
{\end{minipage}}
```

Then code the figure like this

```
\begin{figurehere}{\textwidth}
{\protect\centerline{\includegraphics{fig1.eps}}}
\caption{This is caption.}
\end{figurehere}
```

Comment: Hi Ganapathy, I am facing problem with this code when i am using 5 figueres in one row and with two rows of figures.

Comment: @ashice I think you problem was resolved by using `tabular` environment inside the `figurehere` 

`\begin{figurehere}{\textwidth}
{\protect\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\includegraphics{fig1.eps} &
 \includegraphics{fig2.eps} &
  \includegraphics{fig3.eps} & 
  \includegraphics{fig4.eps} & 
  \includegraphics{fig5.eps}\\
\end{tabular}}
\end{figurehere}`